# Связанные поля autocomplete

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

Есть два `input[type="text"]`, при помощи jQuery Autocomplete UI производится автозаполнение полей из БД, но никак не  могу разобраться, как сделать их связанными:

```js
<?php 
 $link=mysql_connect("DB_host", "DB_user", "DB_passw");
 mysql_select_db("DB_name");
 mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF-8");
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
  $(function() {
    var clipAuthors = [
 <?php
      $query="SELECT `author` FROM `clips` GROUP BY `author`;";
   $res=mysql_query($query);
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
      {
          echo '"'.$row['author'].'",';
   }
  ?>
    ];
 j( "#searchClipAuthor" ).autocomplete({
      source: clipAuthors
    });
 
 var clipTitles = [
 <?php
      $query="SELECT `title` FROM `clips`  GROUP BY `title`;";
   $res=mysql_query($query);
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
      {
          echo '"'.$row['title'].'",';
   }
  ?>
    ];
 j( "#searchClipTitle" ).autocomplete({
      source: clipTitles
    });
 
  });
  </script>
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Поиск по исполнителю" name="searchClipAuthor" id="searchClipAuthor">
<input type="text" placeholder="Поиск по композиции" name="searchClipTitle" id="searchClipTitle">
```

Таблица `clips` имеет 3 поля: `id`, `author`, `title`

И мне нужно, чтобы в инпуте `searchClipTitle` выводились `Title` соответствующие выбранному `Author`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо вынести обработку autocomplete для второго инпута в отдельный файл, и обращаться к нему через AJAX запрос. В объекте autocomplete есть опция - source, которая позволяет это сделать.

В итоге должно получиться что-то вроде

```
$("#searchClipTitle").autocomplete({
    source: "/ajax/titlesearch.php?author=" + $("#searchClipAuthor").val(),
});
```

**EDIT**:

В файле должен формироваться массив, и передаваться в формате json. Документация - http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Пример titlesearch.php

```
$return = array();
$q = $_REQUEST['author'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT distinct `title` FROM `clips` where `title` like '%$q%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    array_push($return,array('label'=>$row['title'],'value'=>$row['title']));
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: А не могли бы вы тогда подсказать, что должно быть в этом файле?
я написал, пока без where, но все равно не работает:
<?php
      $query="SELECT `title` FROM `clips`  GROUP BY `title`;";
   $res=mysql_query($query);
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
      {
          echo '"'.$row['title'].'",';
   }
  ?>

Comment: поправил ответ.

Comment: j( "#searchClipTitle" ).autocomplete({
      source: "/modules/mod_congratulate/autocomplete_title.php?author=" + j("#searchClipAuthor").val(),
    });
autocomplete_title.php
<?php include('/functions/connect_db.php'); ?>
<?php
$return = array();
$q = $_REQUEST['author'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT distinct `title` FROM `clips` where `title` like '%$q%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    array_push($return,array('label'=>$row['title'],'value'=>$row['title']));
}
echo json_encode($return);
?>
Сделал как вы сказали, но все равно не работает

Comment: найдите и поправьте ошибки. файл autocomplete_title.php должен отдавать массив данных в формате json. если вы его получите - ваш скрипт будет работать.

Comment: а можно ли как-нибудь проверить заходит он в этот файл autocomplete_title.php или нет? алерт какой или что-нибудь тип того

Comment: откройте в Firefox. установите расширение Firebug - в нем есть вкладки Console/Network. там можете остлеживать всё что вам нужно, включая переменные Javascript - через функцию console.log();

Comment: Проверил, оно не передает ничего в 
j( "#searchClipTitle" ).autocomplete({ source: "/modules/mod_congratulate/autocomplete_title.php?author=" + $("#searchClipAuthor").val(), });
Выдает /modules/mod_congratulate/autocomplete_title.php?author=&term=s
term=s это введенное во второе поле значение s  и когда ввожу вот это s, он мне выдает все title, даже если в них и не входит s